# What do arimasu and imasu mean in sentences?

Tags: grammar

Can someone please translate and explain to me these sentences from a grammar standpoint?

> Anata no gakkou ni Nani ga arimasu ka?
>
> Anata no ie ni Nani ga arimasu ka?
>
> Doubutsuen ni Nani ga imasu ka?

I know it’s a translation but I really tried all I could to translate them, but they just don't make sense.

Comment: Welcome to the Japanese Language Stack Exchange. Unfortunately (as you seem to be aware), this is a request for a translation. As such, it is likely to be closed unless you can edit it to make your question much more specific and explain how you have tried to find the answer on your own.

Answer (score 1):

*Arimasu* (from [*aru*](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%9C%A8%E3%82%8B)) and *imasu* (form [*iru*](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B1%85%E3%82%8B)) mean "To be, to exist", the difference being that the first is used with inanimate objects, while the second with animate ones.

So your sentences mean respectively "What is in your school?" (*anata no gakkou* being "your school"), "What is in your house?" (*anata no ie* being "your house") and "What is in the zoo?"; in the last sentence using *iru* means the speaker is asking about which animals are in the zoo, and not which structures (or anything inanimate).